# fundamental Pythagorean triangle

Tags: number-theory

Prove that if $r \geq 3$ and r is not $\equiv 2 \mod4$, then there is a fundamental Pythagorean triangle with leg of length r.

Can someone give me a hint how to write a general element out this way? normally you split the expression $r=m^2-n^2$ and look for r

Comment: exactly as you said. Notice that any number can be written as $r=ab$ and you can obtain $m,n$ by solving $m-n=a$, $m+n=b$.

Comment: but i dont know what r is?

Comment: Also that clearly wont work when $r \equiv 0 \mod 4 $ so ill have to use the other one by cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $r=4n$ then $(4n^2-1, 4n, 4n^2+1)=(4n^2-1,r,4n^2+1)$ is a fund. Pyth. triplet.

If $r=2n+1$ then $(2n+1, 2n^2+2n, 2n^2+2n+1)=(r, 2n^2+2n, 2n^2+2n+1)$ is a fund. Pyth. triplet.

The first one is obtained as $(u^2-v^2,2uv, u^2+v^2)$ with $u=2n$ and $v=1.$

The second one is obtained as $(u^2-v^2,2uv,u^2+v^2)$ with $u=n+1$ and $v=n.$

Comment: A fund. Pyth. triplet is $(u^2-v^2,2uv, u^2+v^2)$ where $u,v$ are co-prime members of $ \Bbb N$ with $u>v$ and with $u,v$ not both odd.

Answer (score 1):

If $r = m^2-n^2$ there's no need to go by case, since $m+n$ and $m-n$ are both odd or both even, so 
$$
r = (m-n)(m+n)
$$
implies that $r$ must be odd or multiple of 4.

To prove that there exists $m$ and $n$ such that any $r\not\equiv 2 \pmod 4$ can be written as $r = m^2-n^2$ you can just impose 
$$r= ab \qquad a=m-n \qquad b=m+n$$
to get
$$
m = \frac{a+b}2 \qquad n = \frac{b-a}2
$$
so you need that $a,b$ have the same parity, but if $m$ is odd then $a,b$ are necessarily  odd, and if $m$ is multiple of 4, you can take $a,b$ even.

If you want to find $m,n$, then you have to divide by case:

- $r$ odd $\to$ $m=\frac {r+1}2$, $n=\frac {r-1}2$
- $r$ even $\to $ $m=\frac {r+4}4$, $n=\frac {r-4}4$